# Emoji between ios and android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, emoji

I want to be able to send messages between android and ios devices with the use of emojis.

I know the new android 4.4 supports emoji now but I want to support older devices (2.1 and up).

How do apps like whatsapp allow emojis to be written and viewed even though it is not supported? The only way I could think to accomplish this task is to create custom emojis by creating an image of many emojis and then using the x,y coordinates to get which emoji was selected. The issues with this could be copyright and then when new emojis come out I will always have to update the image and if a user doesn't download the new image they will still have the old emojis and won't be able to view the new ones.

So is there another way of doing this to allow ios emojis to be sent to android and vice versa?

Comment: I have created a small library that supports rendering fallback image on older Android versions: https://github.com/kobjects/emoji The Android emoji seem to be under the Apache license, so using the images from newer versions on older Android versions should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom approach could work. Just add another layer of abstraction -- download the emoji from a central server. Cache it locally. Periodically check to see if there is a new version, and download it. Because it'll remain really simple, old versions of the app will still be able to download and use new emoji whenever you update it.

That is a technical solution to your problem that'll support both platforms. Any copyright concerns are kind of off topic, and very specific to the set of emoji you end up deciding to use.

Comment: is this the only way to implement something like this? It just seems more complicated that it needs to be for a feature that is quite popular

Comment: You could use a font, instead, I suppose -- http://emojisymbols.com/emojilist.php -- Past that, I don't know of other solutions than the one I presented (or affirmed). Hopefully someone more experienced can shed light on this matter. :)

Answer (score 0):

A large set of emoji have been added to [the Unicode standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#In_the_Unicode_standard). So, they're basically just characters you could show with a font. For modern devices, a default font (with new OpenType color support) will be used to show emoji. For older devices, you could simply create your own font or use [open source emoji designs](https://github.com/Genshin/PhantomOpenEmoji) and show them in old school black 'n white.